# Cannot invoke "jdk.internal.platform.CgroupInfo.getMountPoint()" because "anyController" is null

Tags: java, linux, spring, kotlin, gradle

When I try to start my spring / gradle / kotlin (it can be a blank one) application I get this error:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "jdk.internal.platform.CgroupInfo.getMountPoint()" because "anyController" is null
    at java.base/jdk.internal.platform.cgroupv2.CgroupV2Subsystem.getInstance(CgroupV2Subsystem.java:80)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.platform.CgroupSubsystemFactory.create(CgroupSubsystemFactory.java:114)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.platform.CgroupMetrics.getInstance(CgroupMetrics.java:177)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.platform.SystemMetrics.instance(SystemMetrics.java:29)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.platform.Metrics.systemMetrics(Metrics.java:58)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.platform.Container.metrics(Container.java:43)
    at jdk.management/com.sun.management.internal.OperatingSystemImpl.<init>(OperatingSystemImpl.java:182)
    at jdk.management/com.sun.management.internal.PlatformMBeanProviderImpl.getOperatingSystemMXBean(PlatformMBeanProviderImpl.java:280)
    at jdk.management/com.sun.management.internal.PlatformMBeanProviderImpl$3.nameToMBeanMap(PlatformMBeanProviderImpl.java:199)
    at java.management/java.lang.management.ManagementFactory.lambda$getPlatformMBeanServer$0(ManagementFactory.java:488)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$7$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:273)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$2$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:179)
    at java.base/java.util.HashMap$ValueSpliterator.forEachRemaining(HashMap.java:1779)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:509)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:499)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:150)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:173)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:596)
    at java.management/java.lang.management.ManagementFactory.getPlatformMBeanServer(ManagementFactory.java:489)
    at jdk.management.agent/sun.management.jmxremote.ConnectorBootstrap.startLocalConnectorServer(ConnectorBootstrap.java:543)
    at jdk.management.agent/jdk.internal.agent.Agent.startLocalManagementAgent(Agent.java:318)
    at jdk.management.agent/jdk.internal.agent.Agent.startAgent(Agent.java:450)
    at jdk.management.agent/jdk.internal.agent.Agent.startAgent(Agent.java:599)
Exception thrown by the agent : java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "jdk.internal.platform.CgroupInfo.getMountPoint()" because "anyController" is null
```

I have tried different JDKs (16, 17, 18) from different vendors (openjdk, azul, coretto) but the problem persists and I am running out of ideas :( Also recloning from git origin didn't change anything.

I am on Linux - Pop!_OS (which seems to be the cause) and the project is under ~/IdeaProjects/projectname

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: According to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71532170, this could be caused by a missing "memory" entry in the " /proc/cgroups" file.

Comment: Are you trying to run on a Raspberry Pi perchance?  https://github.com/raspberrypi/linux/issues/3644

Comment: Indeed memory cgroup was missing.