# Tomcat Exception: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException after jdk uplift from 11.0.15.1 to 11.0.16

Tags: java, tomcat, java-11, tomcat9

While uplifting the jdk from 11.0.15.1 to 11.0.16 facing following error in the tomcat logs.
**For 11.0.15.1 the tomcat (9.0.65) was working fine with no jdk related error.**

```
        at java.base/jdk.internal.platform.Metrics.systemMetrics(Metrics.java:67)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.platform.Container.metrics(Container.java:43)
        at jdk.management/com.sun.management.internal.OperatingSystemImpl.<init>(OperatingSystemImpl.java:182)
        at jdk.management/com.sun.management.internal.PlatformMBeanProviderImpl.getOperatingSystemMXBean(PlatformMBeanProviderImpl.java:281)
        at jdk.management/com.sun.management.internal.PlatformMBeanProviderImpl$3.nameToMBeanMap(PlatformMBeanProviderImpl.java:198)
        at java.management/java.lang.management.ManagementFactory.lambda$getPlatformMBeanServer$0(ManagementFactory.java:487)
        at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$7$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:271)
        at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$2$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:177)
        at java.base/java.util.HashMap$ValueSpliterator.forEachRemaining(HashMap.java:1692)
        at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:484)
        at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:474)
        at java.base/java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:150)
        at java.base/java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:173)
        at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
        at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:497)
        at java.management/java.lang.management.ManagementFactory.getPlatformMBeanServer(ManagementFactory.java:488)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.Registry.getMBeanServer(Registry.java:463)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleMBeanBase.initInternal(LifecycleMBeanBase.java:55)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.initInternal(StandardServer.java:997)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:136)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:724)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:746)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.load(Bootstrap.java:305)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:475)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.platform.Metrics.systemMetrics(Metrics.java:63)
        ... 27 more
Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
        at java.base/jdk.internal.platform.CgroupSubsystemFactory.create(CgroupSubsystemFactory.java:94)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.platform.CgroupMetrics.getInstance(CgroupMetrics.java:167)
        ... 32 more
Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 4 out of bounds for length 1
        at java.base/jdk.internal.platform.cgroupv2.CgroupV2Subsystem.initSubsystem(CgroupV2Subsystem.java:72)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.platform.cgroupv2.CgroupV2Subsystem.<clinit>(CgroupV2Subsystem.java:43)
        ... 34 more
```

Can someone please tell how to resolve the same?

Comment: I have similar issues in Wildfly 16, exactly after upgrading to 11.0.16.

Comment: It is very likely that the answer is here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71585718/623144

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is from the java side, as in jdk-11.0.16 they have made some changes in cgroups metric calls. As the Cgroups detection logic used JDK-11.0.16 not right on systems which support cgroups v1, but don't have controllers mounted on a cgroups v1 hierarchy. This issue will be resolved in jdk-11.0.17.

Comment: Thanks for the information. I see the new patch with JDK version 11.0.16.1 has been released for JDK now, so I guess we can use this JDK version to get this issue resolved.